# Why didn't Starfleet go to red alert on this?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In S01E02 of *Star Trek: Discovery*,

> T'Kuvma agreed to a peace dialog and then he rammed his ship into the USS Europa in a cloaked state. But, when his ship went invisible,

why didn't Starfleet notice it and go to red alert?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### T'Kuvma didn't cloak his ship

The *Europa* was rammed by a different ship under T'Kuvma's command, which was already cloaked.

This had been my impression watching the episode, but as evidence I'll submit the following:

- The [StarTrek.com database entry for Admiral Anderson](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/admiralanderson) leaves the attacking Klingon ship unnamed, despite having [a separate entry](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/sarcophagus) for T'Kuvma's flagship:

  > Starfleet Admiral at the Battle at the Binary Stars. He was killed when a Klingon cleeve ship attacked the *U.S.S. Europa.*
- The Klingon ship appears atomized after the *Europa* self-destructs, but T'Kuvma's flagship is completely intact after this; there's no evidence of damage until the *Shenzhou* fires on it a few minutes later